# Chrome not working with Robotframework / Selenium2Library

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, robotframework, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use Chrome browser with my Test cases. Same tests work fine with Firefox and PhantomJs.
However , **Chrome browser starts but never opens a page.**

I have installed
1. Chromdriver : port=9515  version=19.0.1068.0  
2. Chrome : Version : 37.0.2062.120 (64-bit) 
3. Selenium: Version : 2.42.1   
4. RobotFramework : Version : 2.8.5

I think I have Paths variables configured accordingly as well. 
google-chrome , starts Chrome 
chromedriver , starts chromeDriver

Following line is responsible for starting chrome and opening page.

```
    *** Variables ***
  ${BROWSER}             Chrome
  ${MY-URL}            http://www.google.com/


Open Browser | ${MY-URL} | ${BROWSER}
```

Errors :
Chrome:

```
WebDriverException: Message: u'Unable to either launch or connect to Chrome. Please check that ChromeDriver is up-to-date. Using Chrome binary at: /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome'
```

WebDriver Logs Shows Error

```
      Initializing session with capabilities {
       "browserName": "chrome",
       "chromeOptions": {
          "args": [  ],
          "extensions": [  ]
       },
       "javascriptEnabled": true,
       "platform": "ANY",
       "version": ""
    }

    [1.001][INFO]:      Launching chrome: /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --disable-hang-monitor --disable-prompt-on-repost --dom-automation --full-memory-crash-report --no-default-browser-check --no-first-run --ignore-certificate-errors --homepage=about:blank
    [46.004][SEVERE]:   Failed to initialize connection

<br><br>
```

Can someone point something I am missing ? 
Anyother way of debuging the problem ? Any Clue will be good.

Comment: Do you see any errors?

Comment: Chromedriver version of 19.0.1068.0 does not make sense. The latest major/minor version is 2.10

Comment: Thanks @ombre42 . Updating Chromedriver worked

Answer (score 2):

Have you put **chromedriver** in your PATH ?

And do you run the test with current **user** or with root ?

Selenium needs chromedriver to call chrome, so you can download it from google.com and put it in /usr/bin, or just update your PATH environment variable.
Then, on Debian, root can't (otherwise with errors) call google-chrome browser, so try it with your account.

Hope it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

NODE,

1. Please re-check your web driver, delete chrome web driver and download new web driver: [Here](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html)
2. Check your **VARIABLE NAME** again! Do NOT use the "**-**" character to set a variable name like ${MY-URL}! You should change it => ${MY_URL}
3. You can try to turn of UAC or/and Firewall and try again.

As i know, when you use selenium2library, you don't need to set path to web driver(!?)

Hope it helpful.

Comment: Thanks  . Updating Chromedriver worked. I do not have enough reputations to Give you +1 for answer. But I can vouch that you pointed to correct things